# Trying to shuffle textFields

Tags: reactjs

So I put them into an array and gave them the shuffle function. The problem is that each time I type something into the text, the state gets updated which renders the component. Thus, for each letter I type, the textFields shuffle.

[The code that is giving me the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCMMM.png)

Comment: when do you want them to shuffle?

Comment: show your code as text. *Plz Plz Plz help :(*

Comment: I would like to shuffle when when the user refreshes the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when there is a change in state, render function is invoked and your *Aa1Array* get shuffled due to that is inside the render. You can move your *Aa1Array* out of the render function and put it into component constructor like below

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.Aa1Array = shuffle([
        <TextField/>,
        <TextField/>,
    ], {copy: true});
 }

 render() {
    let textFields = this.Aa1Array.map(Aa1 => Aa1);
    return (<div>{textFields}</div>);
 }
}
```

Remember to initialize your *this.state = {};* in the constructor before using to get rid of *undefined*.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you! But the only problem is that the hint text is not disappearing when I click on it. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: I am not sure which TextField library that you're using. Can you attach your whole source code file?